# Why Ember focus-out not working?

Tags: ember.js

I have to call 'route' action when input is focus out.

template.js :

```
{{input value=password type="password" focus-out="passwordValidate" class="form-control"}}
```

route.js :

```
actions : {
    passwordValidate : function(){
        if(this.get('password').length<6){
            this.set('validPassword',false);
         }else{
             this.set('validPassword',true);
         }
    }
}
```

But the action did not get called. Whats wrong with the code ?

Comment: nothing seems wrong. what is your ember version?

Comment: @ykaragol : "ember": "lts-2-8"

Comment: The action should be in controller not router

Comment: Are you sure `{{input` code is in template.hbs ? I suspect it is in component.hbs .